# Divide the html page into several pages automatically like MS WORD

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Is ther any way to divide a html context contained div, p and table tages into separated pages in separated div tages (or at least just separated) for a defined height? (like ms word but online)

I want to create an html template for formal letters that might have multiple pages.
Expected a solution by using php or javascript or just html and css.

I use a persian font not english !

By the way, is there any other ways for creating those types of templates? (not using third party websites)... If yes, please give an example.

Note that I want to create pdf and image and ms word doc from that html too!

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you mean several pages on the screen, or several pages when printed?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

with just html and css you can achieve it. look into my below code.

```html
<style>

@media print {
    .pagebreak { page-break-before: always; } /* page-break-after works, as well */
}
</style>

<div class="container pageBreak">
Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit necessitatibus nihil incidunt officia labore blanditiis atque soluta, optio laboriosam voluptates fugit, sint porro iure deleniti eveniet dolor voluptas, possimus repellat.
</div>
<div class="container pageBreak">
Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit necessitatibus nihil incidunt officia labore blanditiis atque soluta, optio laboriosam voluptates fugit, sint porro iure deleniti eveniet dolor voluptas, possimus repellat.
</div>
```

you can either use ctl + p in windows or cmd+p in mac for printing pdf

Answer (score -1):

welcome to Stack Overflow!

It is difficult to answer your question without seeing your code. You get the best answers here if you create the most simple example possible which demonstrates what you are doing, what you have tried and what you want to achieve - and include the code in your question. Developers love to see code :)

However, since this is your first post on Stack Overflow, I want you to feel welcome, so I will try to give a simple answer to the question you asked in the title; How do I divide the HTML page into several pages automatically when it is printed?

The keys are the css properties [break-inside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside) and [break-after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after)

If you have something like this:

```
<article>
  <p>Some paragraph</p>
  <p>Another paragraph</p>
</article>
```

You want the content inside the article to break automatically when necessary, but you don't want a page break to split your paragraphs - you want any page break to occur *after* a paragraph. So you set css rules for `article { break-inside: auto; }` and `p {break-inside: avoid; break-after: auto; }`

Here is a complete example:

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

section > header {
  height: 2in;
  text-align: center;
}

article {
  margin: 0 1in;
  break-inside: auto;
}

article > header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

h1,h2 {
  margin-top: 0
}

p {
  break-inside: avoid;
  break-after: auto;
}

footer {
  break-inside: avoid;
}

#date {
  text-align: right;
}

#signature {
  height: 1in;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section>
  <header>
    <h1>The Letterhead</h1>
  </header>
  <article>
    <header>
      <p>
        {to: name}<br>
        {to: address}
      </p>
      <p id="date">{date}</p>
    </header>
    <div id="content">
      <p>Dear: {name}</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>    
    <footer>
      <p>Sincerely: {name}<p>
      <p id="signature"> </p>
      <p>
        {position} <br>
        {company} <br>
        {telephone} <br>
        {email} <br>
      </p>
    </footer>
  </article>
</section>
```